# sklearn kfold returning wrong indexes in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using kfold function from sklearn package in python on a df (data frame) with non-contious row indexes.

this is the code:

```
kFold = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=None)
for train_index, test_index in kFold.split(dfNARemove):...
```

I get some train_index or test_index that doesn't exist in my df.

what can I do?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

kFold iterator yields to you positional indices of train and validation objects of DataFrame, not their non-continuous indices. You can access your train and validation objects by using `.iloc` pandas method:

```
kFold = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=None)
for train_index, test_index in kFold.split(dfNARemove):
    train_data = dfNARemove.iloc[train_index]
    test_data = dfNARemove.iloc[test_index]
```

If you want to know, which non-continuous indices used for train_index and test_index on each fold, you can do following:

```
non_continuous_train_index = dfNARemove.index[train_index]
non_continuous_test_index = dfNARemove.index[test_index]
```

Comment: I still can see that my df row names are: 1, 3 , 4 , 5 , 7 .. and i get train_index: 0 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7... test_index: 1 , 2, 16 ...

Comment: Iterator yields to your positional indices, not your indices from dfNARemove.index. It's written in answer. .loc method allows you to get objects by positional indices.

Comment: positional indices start from 0, and end with len(dfNARemove)-1, or range(0, len(dfNARemove)). Your DataFrame object's indices may be different from positional indices. It's ok.

Comment: @EduardIlyasov I noticed that the way you access each successive split's positional indexes is like accessing a dictionary's keys and values. Are the different corresponding sets of train and test sets mapped to each other and aggregated by which split they play the role of train/test data? Are they mapped like a dictionary where the keys are the split identifiers/indexes and the values are the corresponding train and test positional indexes?